# http request from an android device

Tags: android

what is the best way to do http requests from an Android device using java?
which changes are necessary to do in the manifest?

Comment: This seems NAT IP, your computer might have access to it, and work when you use browser. Make sure your android has access for it too, try opening it with browser in android phone and see if it works.

Comment: it is working with the android browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call any api which you are calling as url in your android application using [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

First of all, request a permission to access network, add following to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Following AsyncTask will be used to call http get method api in seperate thread:

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    String server_response;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
     URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(uri[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                server_response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                Log.v("CatalogClient", server_response);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Do anything with response..
    }
}


// Converting InputStream to String

private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
    }


To call this class you have to write:    new RequestTask ().execute("http://10.0.0.3/light4on");
```

Comment: Thanks!
@ url = new URL(strings[0]);
AS marks strings as an error?
sorry for the stupid question.. I am new to java

Comment: Updated. Now you can check

Comment: thanks!
but its not working...
logcat says:
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false

Comment: just hit your url in browser and check if you are getting anything or not

Comment: your url method is GET or POST?

Comment: I´m not using PHP
The problem was that there was no content in the body of the page.
I added a h1 and now it is working.
Thanks!!!